# Centralized Certificates and IIS10 - Still using old cert on rollover

Tags: ssl-certificate, iis-10

Every year we reissue our SSL Certificate and we just recently started using Centralized Certificates in IIS.

We exported our Certificate into the Centralized Certificate store and  everything looks recognized and appropriate.

We removed the older cert, that will be expiring soon from the Centralized store.

However, it looks like the old cert is still being served up when checking the certificate in chrome and there is no way to directly specify which Centralized Certificate your service is using:

> Note that there is no need to select a specific corresponding
> certificate to be used. Through the use of the naming contract, the
> corresponding certificate is selected automatically. In this example,
> IIS tries to read centralcert0.pfx from the central SSL certificate
> file share.

Maybe when the old cert expires it will rollover to the new cert...but we'd like to test the newly issued certificate and ensure it is working properly.

How do you uncache the certificate or specify which cert a service should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to manually specify a new certificate in IIS:

1. Open IIS Manager, expand the web server, expand sites
2. Right click Default Website or the website in question and click "Edit Bindings…"
3. Next select port 443 in the bindings list, or any other ports using SSL
4. Click the SSL certificate dropdown to select the desired certificate (you can click View to verify the properties of the cert are what you expect)

Comment: Correct, you can verify the certificate and properties are usable through the single / non centralized certificate. Still, under the centralized certificates, I have removed all but the new certificate but it is still showing the old certs Issued On and Expires On dates.

Comment: By forcing the change on one service that was using the centralized certificate store to directly bind to the certificate, then switching back to centralized certificates, it updated the certificate and all services that were using that centralized were also uncached.